# Rich text box text with formatting does not save in SQL for VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am working on vb form project in which i have RTB (rich text box),
I just want to save formatted text save into SQL also math type character.It saves but with out formatting and miss some math character?
here is my code

```
        Dim sname As Integer = Integer.Parse(txt1.Text)
        Dim sfname As Integer = 2
        Dim scnic As String = rtb.SelectedText 
        query &= "INSERT INTO tencmpC1 (qnumber,topic,Umcq)"


        query &= "VALUES (@qnumber, @topic,@Umcq )"


        Using conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
            Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                With comm
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = query
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@qnumber", sname)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@topic", sfname)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Umcq", scnic)
             conn.Open()

                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    txt10.Text = "question saved "
                End With



            End Using
```

here below is the code where i formated RTB

```
If FontDlg.ShowDialog() <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        rtb.SelectionFont = FontDlg.Font
```

Image below show result while in RTB at inserting time and in sql out when out from sql with out formating?
[image]

I am using nvarchar as datatype of UMCQ table of sql.

Also math character not supported.
[image]

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s what should i have to use against .addwithvalue()

Comment: Read the article - and use `sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ParamName", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 42;` instead - to be able to explicitly define the **datatype** for your parameter!

Comment: @marc_s i try this                         .Parameters.Add("@Umcq", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = scnic
but nothing changed data saved as early with out formating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are saving `rtb.SelectedText` to the database rather than `rtb.SelectedRtf`.  The `SelectedText` is a property which only ever returns the plain text.  The `SelectedRtf` property is the one that returns the value containing all of the rich-text formatting.

Comment: i try rtb.SelectedRtf and enter"ssssssssssssssssssscccccccccccccccczz" ,but got this in grid view'{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Monotype Corsiva;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ul\b\i\f0\fs32 ssssssssssssssssssscccccccccccccccczz\par
}'

Comment: Correct.  That's what RTF looks like.  You need to display it in a control that supports RTF formatting.

Comment: i need to display it in a grid view and crystal report same problem on both side?

Comment: I'm not well versed in either of those controls.  I wouldn't necessarily expect the "grid view" control support rich text, though maybe there would be some way to dock a rich text box control inside of your grid control.  Again, I've never used crystal reports, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't have a way to show rich text.  Either way, those are new questions.  This question was about how to save rich text to the database, which you now have successfully done.

Comment: And what about math type character

Comment: Presumably, that's just a character in a particular font.  Once you get the RTF displaying properly, it should show that character properly.  To test it, you could try displaying what you read from SQL in a `RichTextBox` control.  If even the rich text box control doesn't display the math character properly, then it must be an issue of the character being lost due to encoding.  If so, you should check to make sure that the data-type of the column in the database supports unicode (e.g. `nvarchar` vs. `varchar`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84262/discussion-between-sonia-rehman-and-steven-doggart).